# make video from image sequences on Mac os X

Tags: image, video, sequence

I have a sequence of images. I need to convert it to video. I know ffmpeg using linux. Is there any librairie on Mac os x?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [OpenCV library](http://opencv.org/) by applying [`VideoWriter`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter) class to write to a video given sequence of images.

Check out [Creating a video with OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.1/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html) for examples.

Comment: @phdstudent You can still use `ffmpeg` in MacOS. Check out [here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html).